# IIS 7 - "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage" when anonymous access is turned off

Tags: iis-7, internet-explorer, integrated-authentication

I've got an ASP .NET website running on IIS 7.  I'm trying to use Integrated Windows Authentication but having a hard time with IE.  In IIS, I've enabled Windows and Forms Authentication and disabled anonymous authentication.  Everything is working smoothly in Chrome but IE gives me a generic message:

"Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage"

As soon as I enable anonymous authentication in IIS, I can view the page properly in IE (but without proper authentication).

Googling the problem has given me some suggesions, none of which have worked.  I've double checked that Keep-Alives are enabled and I've tried enabling and disabling Kernel mode authentication in IIS.

The host-header I'm using to access the website is not the same as the actual name of the webserver machine, if that makes any difference, but the host-header has been mapped to 127.0.0.1 in the hosts file.

Any ideas?

UPDATE: According to this: http://mvolo.com/iis-70-twolevel-authentication-with-forms-authentication-and-windows-authentication/

Using Integrated Windows Auth and Forms Auth at the same time does not work properly when the app pool is in integrated mode.  I switched over to classic mode and now IE is able to display the site properly, although I have a new problem ... IE will not accept any cookies so the session is not sticking ....

UPDATE 2: Problen solved, apparently a host header with an underscore messes IE up big time.  Cookies won't work and mixed mode auth + integrated app pool mode either.

Solution:  Access the website with another host header that does not contain an underscore and problem goea away!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution: apparently a host header with an underscore messes IE up big time. Cookies won't work and mixed mode auth + integrated app pool mode either.

Solution: Access the website with another host header that does not contain an underscore and problem goes away!